# FFMPEG shell execution with PHP - Unusual Error Because of GCC

Tags: php, gcc, ffmpeg, xampp, lampp

I've been trying to debug the PHP Script, but the error message that I receive is very unusual.

- CP, MV , WHOAMI  - all these commands work with shell_exec
- FFMPEG is installed
- apache user - **nobody** with read write execute permission for **nogroup** to /usr/bin/ffmpeg.
- FFMPEG working fine in terminal.
- GCCPP is installed and GCC package is also installed.
- Working with shell PHP command (brock@ubuntu~$ php runthis.php)

Code I ran:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i beep.mp3 -ac 1 -ar 48000 -ab 128k audio1.mp3 2>&1', $out, $rv);
echo "output is:\n".implode("\n", $out)."\nexit code:$rv\n";
```

I get the following error:

```
output is: ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.0.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libdirac_encoder.so.0) ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6) exit code:1
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: It would appear you've got ffmpeg components that were compiled by different GCC versions (4.0/4.2) and the support libraries for those two versions aren't present.

Answer (score 3):

ffmpeg is looking in /opt/lampp/lib for libgcc. This is currently an out of date lib. Copy libgcc_s.so.1 from /lib to /opt/lampp/lib.